# Generating a range of numbers as strings Python

Tags: python, loops

I need to loop over a number of files with structured files names.

They are of the form 'Mar00.sav', 'Sep00.sav', 'Mar01.sav'

At the moment I do this;

```
Years = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17']
```

Which works but I was wondering if there is a better way?

I tried range but  `str(range(00,17))` will drop the leading zeros...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the same issue and there is a perfect solution to it -[zfill](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_zfill.htm) method

An example of usage:

```
>>> str('1').zfill(7)
'0000001'
```

What you need to do is to create a generator for N numbers and fill its string representation with zeros.

```
>>> for i in range(1, 18):
...     str(i).zfill(2)
...
'01'
'02'
'03'
...
'16'
'17'
```

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> [str(i).zfill(2) for i in range(1,18)]
['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17']
```

Answer (score 4):

In python 2.7 , you can achieve it like this

```
>>> ["%02d" %i for i in range(0,17)]
['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16']
>>>
```

if you want to print

```
>>> for i in range(00,17):
        print '%02d' %i


00
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
>>>
```

Comment: In Python 2.7 the formatting method for string objects is already supported. So you can be compatible with Python 3.x by doing this: `["{:02}".format(n) for n in range(17)]`

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 you can use f string:

```
>>>[f"{i:02d}" for i in range(0,17)]
['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16']
```